# Cannot save params using update_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a javascript that will transform numbers to words and it uses a input id= Spanish.
http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/RQ7R4/74/

I created other javascript that will show the input value into a text_field_tag like a repeated value.

```
 <script>window.onload=function(){document.getElementById('money_word').value=document.getElementById('Spanish').value;}</script>
```

I'm trying to update a column in "action show" but is not updating anything and seems that is not reading money_word params

Here is the table

```
|invoices|
  |id|  |money|   |money_word|
    1     1000      one thousand
    2     2000      two thousand
    3     3000      three thousand
```

Here is the controller

```
def show
  @invoice=  Invoice.find[params[:id]]
  @money= params[:money_word].to_s
  @query=  Invoice.update_all(["money_word = '#{@money}' ",@money  ], ["id = ?",params[:id] ])
end
```

Here is the view according:

```
 <input id="Spanish" NAME="Spanish" class="input_blank" value="ONE THOUSAND"
 <script>window.onload=function(){document.getElementById('money_word').value=document.getElementById('Spanish').value;}</script>

 <%= text_field_tag "money_word", @money  %>
```

Here is the log:

```
Processing InvoiceController#show (for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-25 15:39:44) [GET]
  Parameters: {"id"=>"57"}
  Invoice Load (0.1ms)   SELECT * FROM `invoices` WHERE (`invoices`.`id` = 1) 
  Invoice Update (34.7ms)   UPDATE `invoices` SET money_word = '' WHERE (id = '1') 

Rendering invoice/show
```

Please somebody can help me or advise me other way to save the traslation of the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are doing that in show action but try :

```
params[:invoice][:money_word]
```

instead

```
params[:money_word]
```

Comment: Where? how is the sintaxis?

Comment: In show action, you need put this 
@money= params[:invoice][:money_word]

Comment: I did it and got "You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]"

Comment: Not sure. Can you give me your url path ?

Comment: So obviously you don't have params[:money] in your url . You can't call params[:money] because you don't have any additional parameter in your url,so it returns nil .

Comment: Btw why you have show in your url ? I'm not sure that you are working correctly .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56382/discussion-between-zauzaj-and-carlitos-morales).

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use update_all since you are updating a single record. Just call update_attributes on the @invoice you already loaded:

```
@invoice.update_attributes(money_word: @money)
```

Comment: I tried it but i get this:
  Invoice Update (45.8ms)   UPDATE `invoices` SET money_word = '' WHERE (id = '1') 
  SQL (0.1ms)   BEGIN
  SQL (0.1ms)   COMMIT

Comment: Seems is not saving the parameter

Comment: If you want to try with update_all, try changing it to: `Invoice.update_all({:money_word => @money}, {:id => params[:id]})`